# How can I create a IDataObject instance with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ole, idataobject

This [C++ code shows how OLE can be used to simulate a file drag and drop to simulate a  'Send to...' operation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/sendtomail.aspx). This will open the standard mail client with the selected file(s) as an attachment, a very interesting alternative to the mailto: protocol handler.

Which is the best (short and safe) way to create the neccessary instance of IDataObject in Delphi?

I have found some code [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=2335) but maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porting the C++ code to Delphi probably isn't too difficult.
Start with

```
type
  TDataObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IDataObject)
```

and implement the required methods as shown in the C++ example.

Comment: Yes I agree it actually looks not so hard to port. Maybe I could use the GetUIObjectOf method of IShellFolder, see my Delphi code example link, without implementing IDataObject.